# ERROR 403 - FORBIDDEN on including FULL url as query string parameter

Tags: 7

after moving to new server, i started to get 403 on the following link...any help?

http://www.mywebsite.com/redirect/89431/?url=http://www.externalWebSite.com/blog/2014/10/05/

the goal is to redirect the user to the external website.

below is the module (even i dont think the problem is from it)

```
<?php

function redirect_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['redirect/%'] = array(
        'title' => 'Go To URL',
        'page callback' => 'page_redirect',
        'page arguments' => array(1,2),
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
     );
    return $items;
}
function page_redirect($arg1) {
    $nid = $arg1;
    if (is_numeric($nid)) {
        if(node_load($nid)){
        db_merge('node_counter')
          ->key(array('nid' => $nid))
          ->fields(array(
            'daycount' => 1,
            'totalcount' => 1,
            'timestamp' => REQUEST_TIME,
          ))
          ->expression('daycount', 'daycount + 1')
          ->expression('totalcount', 'totalcount + 1')
          ->execute();
        }
    }
    if (isset($_GET['url'])){
        drupal_goto($url);
    }
}

?>
```

NOTE:
THE FOLLOWING DO NOT GIVE 403 ERROR (NOTE AFTER THE http in the query string):

http://www.mywebsite.com/redirect/89431/?url=http//www.externalWebSite.com/blog/2014/10/05/

http://www.mywebsite.com/redirect/89431/?url=http:/www.externalWebSite.com/blog/2014/10/05/

Comment: Do you have mod_security enabled in Apache?

Comment: thx for showing me the light :) ... that solved the problem. it seems that hostgator has enabled the  mod_security and stopped any "http://" in form data ("Remote File Injection attempt in ARGS (MM)") ... found this after googling about mod_security http://forums.hostgator.com/mod-security-and-403-errors-t71394.html

Comment: Good to hear that. There is also a risk of Open Redirect. IMHO, mod_security is good enough to detect the dumbest security errors, and when you have taken care of the basic security, mod_security just gets in your way.